# Pasting multiple images in a word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need assistance in building a macro that would take the image that is stored in the clipboard and paste it in the word doc. There will be multiple images so sequential images must be pasted at the end of the document.

Here is my current code so far

' Create word document and paste to word

```
Set wordobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objdoc = wordobj.Documents.Add
wordobj.Visible = True
Set objSelection = wordobj.Selection
objSelection.Paste
```

' Paste in the active end of the word document
'??? tried multiple lines but it gives "object" error

```
objdoc.ActiveDocument.Content 
objdoc.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
objSelection.Paste.Paste
```

Any assistance will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since your code creates a new document each time it's run, the only way there'd be anything to paste over is if that new document already has some content. But since you don't even specify a template to load from, that can only mean Word's 'Normal' template, which should never have any content. Regardless, it's as simple as:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wordobj As Object, objdoc As Object
Set wordobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objdoc = wordobj.Documents.Add
With objdoc.Range
  .InsertAfter vbCr
  .Characters.Last.Paste
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, the code suggested gives me a property method error. What I currently have  is a code that will take a screenshot of a report from Internet explorer. What I need assistance on is a code that will open a word doc and paste the image onto word and if there is more than one image page is on the active doc at the end of the document.

Comment: The code as posted works fine for me with no errors. Regardless, 'wordobj.Documents.Add' - which is from your own code - creates a new document; it does not open an existing document.